# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException from dynamic content

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, element

There is [a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe9rz.png) on [this site](http://www.cobar.org/Find-A-Lawyer) and I am trying to get every option from it and click a search button with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('c:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')

driver.get('http://www.cobar.org/Find-A-Lawyer')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
options = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="FAL_FOP_field"]')
for option in options.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text != 'ALL':
        option.click()
        #click search button
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-main"]').click()

        lawyer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr/td[0]')
        print(lawyer)
```

However I am getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":
"Unable to find element with xpath '//select[@id=\"FAL_FOP_field\"]'",
"request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":
"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"115","Content-Type":
"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:52809","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"}
,"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":
"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"e03be070-e353-11e6-83b5-5f7f74696cce\","
" \"value\": \"//select[@id=\\\"FAL_FOP_field\\\"]\"}","url":"/element",
"urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/",
"path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"",
"userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},
"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/e03be070-e353-11e6-83b5-5f7f74696cce/element"}}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Salikhov, there can be 2 possbilities as of now. One is your Xpath might be wrong and the other is that the page is taking more time to load, so you might have to increase the wait time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is because fields you are locating are inside **iFrame**.
So, first you need to switch to iframe and then locate your elements.
still, if didn't work, add time delay.

To locate iFrame :

```
WebElement iframelocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='dnn_ctr2047_IFrame_htmIFrame']"));
```

Then Switch to iFrame

```
driver.switchTo().frame(iframelocator);
```

Add above two steps in your code before locating elements.

**Note** : Above written code is in java.

Comment: As `Iframe` has `id`, you don't have to search it by `XPath`, Just use `driver.switch_to_frame('dnn_ctr2047_IFrame_htmIFrame')`